# How does one or more data step OUTPUT statements work and can it be implicit?

Tags: sas

When running a data step in SAS, why does the output statement seem to 'stop' the iterating of the set statement?

I need to conditionally output duplicate observations. While I can use a plethora of output statements, I'd like if SAS did it's normal iterating and output just created an additional observation.

1) Does the `run` statement in SAS have a built in `output` statement? (The way sum statements have a built in `retain`)

2) What is happening when I ask SAS to output certain observations - in particular after a `set` statement? Will it set all the values until a condition and then only keep the values I request? or does it have some kind of similarities with other statements such as the `point=` statement?

3) Is there a similar statement to `output` that will continue to set the values from a previous data step and then output an additional observation when requested?

For example:

```
data test;
  do i = 1 to 100;
  output;
  end;
run;

data test2;
  set test;
  if _N_ in (4 8 11) then output;
run;

data test3;
  set test;
  if _N_ in (4 8 11) then output;
  output;
run;
```

test has 100 observations, test2 has 3 observations, and test3 has 103 observations. This make me think that there is some kind of built in output statement for either the run statement, or the data step itself.

Comment: Yes, it's fundamental to understanding data step programming that any data step that does *not* have an explicit `output` statement gets an implicit `output`statement right at the end. Whenever you add a conditional output, like in your tests, the implicit `output` is removed and you have to consider whether you need to put it back. See https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/lgref/z0194540.htm for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`output` in SAS is an explicit instruction to write out a row to the output dataset(s) (all of the dataset(s) named in the `data` statement, unless you specify a single dataset in `output`).

`run`, in addition to ending the step (meaning no statements after `run` are processed until that data step is completed - equivalent to the ending `}` in a c-style programming language module, basically) contains an implicit [`return`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000201969.htm) statement.

Unless you are using `link` or `goto`, `return` tells SAS to return to the beginning of the data step loop.  In addition, return contains an implicit `output` statement that outputs rows to all datasets named in the data statement, unless there is an `output` statement in the data step code - in which case that is not present.

It is `return` that causes SAS to actually stop processing things after it - not the output.  In fact, SAS happily does things after the `output` statement; they just may not be output anywhere.  For example:

```
data x;
 do row = 1 to 100;
  output;
  row_prev+1;
 end;
run;
```

That `row_prev+1` statement is executed, even though it's after the output statement - its presence can be seen on the next row.  In your example where you told it to just output three rows, it still processed the other 97 - just nothing was output from them.  If any effects had happened from that processing, it would occur - in fact, the incrementing of `_n_` is one of those effects (`_n_` is not the row number, but the iteration count of data step looping).

You should probably read up on the data step itself.  SAS documentation includes a lot of information on that, or you could read papers like [The Essence of Data Step Programming](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings11/269-2011.pdf).  This sort of thing is quite common in SGF papers, in part because SAS certification requires understanding this fairly well.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand everything is by reading about the [Program Data Vector](http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/125-2013.pdf) (PDV). The short answer to your questions:

- The `output` statement is implied at the `run` boundary of every SAS data step that uses `set`, `merge`, `update`, or (nothing).
- The `set` statement takes the contents of the current row and reads them into the PDV, if you have a single `set` statement
- The `output` statement simply outputs the contents of the PDV at that moment into your output dataset
- SAS only goes to a new row in the source dataset defined by your `set` statement when it reaches a `run` boundary, `delete` statement, `return` statement, or failing the conditions of an `if` without `then` statement
- `point=` forces SAS to go directly to an observation number defined by a variable; otherwise, it will read every row sequentially, one by one

Comment: I would reword the fourth point: it's really `SAS only returns to the top of the data step`, and also `return` can cause this.  SAS goes to a new row in the source dataset anytime it encounters the `set` statement, which you can cause a lot of ways beyond that.

Answer (score 0):

It's implicit at the end, unless it's used in one or more places in that data step.

Each time the execution encounters an `OUTPUT` statement, or the implicit one if it exists, it will output a new row.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.

1) There is an implied `OUTPUT` at the end of the data step, **unless** your data step includes an explicit `OUTPUT` statement.  That is why your first step wrote all 100 observations and the second only three.

2) The `OUTPUT` statement tells SAS to write the current record to the output dataset.

3) There is not a direct way to do what you want to duplicate records without using `OUTPUT` statements, but for some similar problems you can cause the duplication on the input side instead of the output side.

For example if you felt your class didn't have enough eleven year-olds you could make two copies of all eleven year-olds by reading them twice.

```
data want;
  set sashelp.class 
      sashelp.class(where=(age=11))
  ;
  by name;
run;
```